# how to read value from text/config file in flask

Tags: file, flask

I wrote the code to send mail in flask. The form collects all values name, address, email etc. Then the sendmail function uses this email to send mail to some fixed receiver. This receiver's email address is fixed in code. I want to keep that email address in a text file and read that from text file. Please suggest me how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I keep a `settings.py` file for these sorts of things.  Make a new file in the root of your project called `settings.py` and add a variable to it.

```
EMAIL_RECEIVER = 'my_email@email.com'
```

And then you can import this anywhere in your application and use the EMAIL_RECEIVER variable

```
import settings

email.send_mail(to=settings.EMAIL_RECEIVER)
```